# Popup window with javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, popup

i want to open a link via php but with some resources of javascript, otherwise i know that is not possible to do it.

I already have this code, or function :

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
        function open(URL) {

            var width = 150;
            var height = 250;

            var left = 99;
            var top = 99;

            window.open(URL,'janela', 'width='+width+', height='+height+', top='+top+', left='+left+', scrollbars=yes, status=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, fullscreen=no');

        }
    </script>
```

in php i have this and works fine :

```
$inf=' | <a href="javascript:abrir(\'http://google.pt\');">+i</a>';
```

But instead of the static url http://google.pt i want to put a variable of php like this :

```
$inf=' | <a href="javascript:abrir(\'$VARIABLE');">+i</a>';
```

of course is not working, i don't know how to embed the variable into that url, any help?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To let the $variable work you have to DOUBLE QUOTE the string, and escape the inner double quotes with "\" so it doesn't close your string:

```
$inf=" | <a href=\"javascript:abrir('$VARIABLE');\">+i</a>";
```

Or you can use concatenation:

```
$inf=' | <a href="javascript:abrir(\''.$VARIABLE.'\');">+i</a>';
```

Comment: worked in perfection, thanks for the explanation and for the example.

Comment: Do you mean that he should have to bind that function (open()) to a specific class or Id ?

Comment: `<a href="javascript` is often a red flag. Don't use inline events, inline styles, or javascript in the href (unless you absolutely cannot help it).

Comment: oh right, didn't realize it wasn't a onclick u__u, just copy pasted it, cos normally I bind the event through jQuery on page load, but I assumed his javascript knowledge is minimum yet and that would have been a huge explanation :P

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$inf=' | <a href="javascript:abrir(\''.$VARIABLE.'\');">+i</a>';
```

or

```
$inf=" | <a href=\"javascript:abrir('$VARIABLE');\">+i</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The code would be:

```
$inf=' | <a href="javascript:abrir(\''.$variable.'\');">+i</a>';
```

If the variable comes from some outside source (like the url, ....) then be sure to make sure that it cannot be used for code injection (thus htmlspecialchars,.... should be used)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a php variable into a JavaScript function then this can be done like this:

```
$inf=' | <a href="javascript:abrir(\''.$VARIABLE.'\');">+i</a>';
```

You may notice the single quotes used to mark the php strings and the escaped single quote (`\'`) used for JavaScript function on mark the JavaScript strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just have found something different that may help =)

I am no way affiliated with pastebin.

[Array Implementation](http://pastebin.com/M9W0Cc5g)

Comment: I love that you need to announce that you have no affiliation with sites you cross-link. however I think for the most part this is un-needed. If you are affiliated with a site, maybe announce it then, and leave it for us to assume you are not in the other cases. :)